# anime - middle schoolers/highschoolers manifest their magical powers and a bracelet that controls one of the elements appears

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon

I remember watching it in the late 2000s. I can't remember almost anything about the plot except that there were kids, around 14-16, and they were in this like magic school and when their powers manifested, a bracelet that was lowkey shaped like their element would appear. I remember the main character was a girl, and she struggled until her powers manifested and if I'm not mistaken it was wind or something.
There was also a boy and a girl who were a bit older who were the antagonists, and the girl dies, but the principal of the school somehow brings her back...

Sorry, I can't remember more details :') please let me know if you know what I'm talking about <3